# How to disable a link on a widget from another site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I disable the link associated with the widget I added to my website? I don't have access to anything other than the HTML code they provided. An example would be the Trustpilot widget at the bottom of the page in the link. If you click on the widget it takes you to Trustpilot's website, but we don't want that to happen.    https://goldsilver.com/

Comment: If that widget is free then i bet you cant do it as its against license rules.

Answer (score 1):

The widget is an iframe, and when an iframe is cross domain (so the iframe source file is not on your site) you can not change anyting inside of it.
You could put an overlay div over it, but that would block every click on the iframe.

> By the way, you can't do this thing to widgets provided by the vendors, as its against their policies ~ Saumya Rastogi

Just for learning purposes:

```css
#widget {
  width: 450px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
#widget > iframe {
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#widget:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <iframe src="https://widget.trustpilot.com/trustboxes/539ad0ffdec7e10e686debd7/index.html?locale=en-US&templateId=539ad0ffdec7e10e686debd7&businessunitId=4bf1926500006400050c99f2&styleHeight=350px&styleWidth=100%25&theme=light&stars=4%2C5"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this css property to that particular a tag like this:

```
a { pointer-events: none; }
```

```css
a.disabled_link {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="disabled_link">Any Link</a>
```

By the way, you can't do this thing to widgets provided by the vendors, as its against their policies.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I feel compelled to add an answer for the Trustpilot widget in particular.

The following code should disable the click event on a Trustpilot TrustBox widget.

```
.trustpilot-widget{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Depending on your code, you may have to make this an inline style. I did.

```
    <div
      className="trustpilot-widget"
      style={{ pointerEvents: 'none', cursor: 'default' }}
      ...
      ...
      ...
      {your other Trustpilot widget code}
    >
      <a>Trustpilot</a>
    </div>
```

As far as going against Trustpilot policies and/or TOS, this code was provided by someone at Trustpilot in response to an inquiry we made regarding making the widget non-clickable and whether that goes against TOS. So, in short, disabling the link on that particular widget seems to be safe.

If you still have doubt then I would recommend reaching out to them personally. They responded to our inquiry within 24 hours.